# IBM ServeRAID 2 channels SCSI controller compatible with IBM x366 server which use SAS onboard?

Tags: sas, scsi, ibm-xseries, ibm

I own an IBM x360 server in which I have an IBM ServeRAID 2 channels SCSI controller for which I use the two channels.

- Channel 1: the server's HDD.
- Channel 2: IBM EXP300 HDD Enclosure.

Will this IBM ServeRAID SCSI controller work and allow me to use my EXP300 HDD Enclosure with the x366 server, though the x366 has SAS onboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know about specific option/server compatibility, you need to check [ServerProven](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/info/x86servers/serverproven/compat/us/). (It may work even if it's not on the list).

Since the EXP300 talks SCSI and the RAID controller talks SCSI, yes that's just fine.

It's not functionally different between having a computer capable of using both IDE and SATA drives.

Comment: +1 & accepted. Thanks! I thought so, but since I am no server and network specialist, I prefered to verify and not to presume. Your help is pretty much appreciated! And thanks for the ServerProven information.